# Apache mod rewrite rule is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already checked and the MOD REWRITE is up and running on the server.

Request url is:
http ://www.mydomain.com/user/123456

`.htaccess` rule:
`RewriteRule  ^/user/(.*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]`

So in theory it should redirect internally to the php script `user.php`with the variable `u=123456` but nothing is happening? How can I debug that?

```
Not Found
The requested URL /user/65464654 was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` on the .htaccess ?

Comment: Yes i do: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^/user/(.*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Did you try renaming `user.php` to something different? the problem might be related with both file and directory having the same name, also, does dir `user` exists ?

Comment: i did change but no lucky. same problem

Comment: if `.htaccess` is in /user then `RewriteRule  ^\d+$ user.php?user=$0 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if .htaccess is in /user then RewriteRule ^\d+$ user.php?user=$0 [L,QSA]
```

from @Deadooshka works.

Comment: OK ot matches numbers but not characteres

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the leading slash in your pattern. The leading slash is removed from the URI when used to match against rules in an htaccess file. So you want:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `-Multiviews` option may not be needed, it's to ensure mod_negotiation doen't take over and automatically map the request to `user.php` before your rewrite rule can get applied.

Comment: nothing happens.
i wanna translate the www.mydomain.com/user/123456 to www.mydomain.com/user/user.php?user=123456 like a internal redirect